# Suppose $x,y\in R$ and $k\in N$ where $x^k=y$. Then prove ${x^a:a\in Q}={y^a:a\in Q}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $x,y\in R$ and $k\in N$ where $x^k=y$. Then prove {$x^a:a\in Q$}={$y^a:a\in Q$}

All I can intuitively see is that {$x^a:a\in Q$}={$x^{ka}:a\in Q, k\in N$}. This seems false because you can choose some random natural number then ka!=a and $x^a!=x^{ka}$

Comment: Hint: look at the number $y^{\frac{1}{k}}$

Comment: Why don't you start with $\{y^a:a\in Q\}=\{(x^k)^a:a\in Q\}=\{x^{ka}:a\in Q\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- {$x^a:a\in \mathbb Q$} $\subset ${$y^b:b\in \mathbb Q$}

Let $a \in${$x^a:a \in \mathbb Q$}

$a=\frac{c}{d}$ where c,d $\in \mathbb Z$

So $x^a=y^\frac{a}{k}=y^\frac{c}{dk}$ and $dk \in \mathbb Z$.

Then $a \in ${$y^b:b\in \mathbb Q$}.

- {$y^b:b\in \mathbb Q$} $\subset ${$x^a:a \in \mathbb Q$}

Let $b \in${$y^b:b\in \mathbb Q$}

$b=\frac{c}{d}$ where $c,d$ $\in \mathbb Z$

So $y^b=x^{kb}=x^\frac{ck}{d}$ and $ck \in \mathbb Z$.

Then $b \in ${$x^a:a\in \mathbb Q$}.

Finally, {$y^b:b\in \mathbb Q$} = {$x^a:a\in \mathbb Q$}

Comment: Let $a\in\{x^a:a\in\mathbb Q\}$ should not be written like this. You need to use a different variable than $a$ at the left. With some strain you may be able to keep track of which $a$ is which, from the context, but it is not a good practice and results in confusion. There are (most of the time) sufficiently many letters in the alphabet, so you could have written something like let $p\in\{x^a:a\in\mathbb Q\}$, instead of let $a\in\{x^a:a\in\mathbb Q\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you start with $\{y^a:a\in Q\}=\{(x^k)^a:a\in Q\}=\{x^{ka}:a\in Q\}$? Now let $b=ka\in kQ =\{kq:q\in Q\}$. But if $k$ is a non-zero integer then $kQ=Q$ (if $r\in kQ$ then $r=kq$ for some $q\in Q$ but $kq$ is rational, so $r=kq\in Q$; and if $q\in Q$ then $q=k\frac qk\in kQ$ since $\frac qk\in Q$).

Thus $\{x^{ka}:a\in Q\}=\{x^{ka}:ka\in kQ\}=\{x^b:b\in kQ\}=\{x^b:b\in Q\}$. Since $b$ is a dummy variable, we may replace it with any other dummy variable, so $\{x^b:b\in Q\}=\{x^a:a\in Q\}$. We had started with $\{y^a:a\in Q\}$ and ended with $\{x^a:a\in Q\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Thought of this,

Take real numbers m and n and a rational number p/q such that p and q are natural numbers. Now for every number m^(p/q) can be written as n^p, such that m^(1/q) = n.

Using this analogy, the set { x^a : a belongs to Q } is the same as { x^k : k belongs to N }.

The same can be thought for y^a, taking y = x^n where n is a natural number. Then, do the analogy in reverse, and you raise every term to n. This is also reduced to the same expression as before. This proves the statement.

If this is correct, then negative sign can be incorporated in the exponents for the analogy.

Comment: $\{2^k:k\in N\}=\{2,4,8,16,...\}$ (perhaps including $1$ if $0\in N$). But $\{2^a:a\in Q\}$ includes many other values, like $\frac12,\frac18,\sqrt{2},\frac1{\sqrt[5]{2}}$,

Comment: x can take any real value so the set of values which you gave for 2^a can be obtained (are) in the set x^n, it's just that x takes values like 2^(1/4) and so on. So, the argument goes further than this example. That is the crux of the analogy.